# How to watch NASA TV without installing plugins?

Tags: video

I just found [this video](http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/index.html) on "NASA TV", but I don't feel like installing a plugin to my relatively pristine Chrome. Can I watch it without a plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NASA TV has switched to H.264 video over either Flash (for most browsers) or HTML5 (for iOS).

If Flash plugin is unacceptable, you'll need to fake your userAgent as an iPad and go to http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/nasatv_live_iphone.html

Comment: Sorry for asking, but is that a yes or a no, on the OP's question?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're going to have to install plugin. Shame they use Real player.

**Edit:** Unless of course you can find a way of getting someone to stream it, download the content and then convert it.